# Javascript marker not working when put into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a website that features a Google map with my custom markers on it. Each marker has its own link, and I can easily link each marker to a URL as follows (this example has only one of my markers) -

```
 var image = 'parkour.png';
 var locations = [
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.670231, -79.386821),
      map: map,
      url: "http://bit.ly/RDYwKQ",
      icon: image
    })
  ]
  google.maps.event.addListener(locations[0], 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = locations[0].url;
  });
```

As you can see, I am simply creating an array, adding an element, and then linking the element. This works fine. However, when I loop through each element to add a listener to each one, not a single marker has a link (they all still appear, and still cause the mouse to change as though there is a link, but clicking does nothing). Here is the code for that -

```
  var image = 'parkour.png';
  var locations = [
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.670231, -79.386821),
      map: map,
      url: "http://bit.ly/RDYwKQ",
      icon: image
    })
  ]
  for(x in locations) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(x, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = x.url;
    })
  }
```

Note that the only change is that the elements are looped through and called in this way.

I've tried everything, from changing it to a normal for-loop, to creating a marker first and then adding it to the array, and I can't seem to find any fix.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `for in` statement to loop over an array. The `for in` statement iterate over all the keys of an object and yields that key. To loop over an array, use a simple `for` loop instead.

Also, as a good practice, you should have a single `var` statement and limit property lookups as much as possible. Additionnaly, you must be careful with closures: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
var i = 0,
    len = locations.length,
    addListener = google.maps.event.addListener,
    l;

    for(; i < len; i++) {
        addListener((l = locations[i]), 'click', (function(l) {
            return function () {
                window.location.href = l.url;
            };

        })(l));
     }
```

Comment: As mentioned in OP, I have tried this, but it fails to result in any solution. Would you happen to have any other ideas? I'm up for anything by now.

Comment: Beautiful; any chance you know why this works, and mine doesn't?

Comment: @Simon, have a look at the link I posted about closures ;)

Comment: javascript function closure. [Mike Williams' explanation from his Google Maps API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm)